# Setting two different value on an enum variable

Tags: java, enums

I have been trying to assign value on the enum variable but I couldn't succeed it.
So what I want is THIS to have two values of `optionOne` and `optionTwo`.
So that `A.valueOf("THIS");` will bring value `A.getOptionOne()` of 2 and `A.getOptionTwo()` of 4.

From Eclipse I get an error line

```
"The nested type A cannot hide an enclosing type" on
<< public enum A {THIS("2","4"), IS("4","7"), REAL("12.5","29")}; >>
```

I want some advise :(

//edit : I will work on the error message it really isn't related, I want to get a guide of methodology of setting two different values on a single enum variable.

```
public class A {

    public enum A {THIS("2","4"), IS("4","7"), REAL("12.5","29")};

    private final String optionOne;
    private final String optionTwo;

    private A(String optionOne, String optionTwo){
        this.optionOne= optionOne;
        this.optionTwo= optionTwo;
    }

    public String getOptionOne(){
        return optionOne;
    }

    public String getOptionTwo(){
        return optionTwo;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `Vehicle` ? What is `Vehicle ` ?

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with the code you posted , please post a [mcve] .

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry, I wanted to generalize the question I was asking rather than just posting my code. because I wanted a direction of how to set two values for one enum variable, not debugging.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I have tried but I don't think that is the main issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong: your enum definition is hiding the name of identically-named class that it's in.

Java's enums are a special type of class, in which the enum constants are the only allowed instances. Therefore, you don't have to enclose your enum in another class. Just provide the methods inside the enum definition:

```
public enum A {
    THIS("2","4"), IS("4","7"), REAL("12.5","29");

    private final String optionOne;
    private final String optionTwo;

    A(String optionOne, String optionTwo){
        this.optionOne= optionOne;
        this.optionTwo= optionTwo;
    }

    public String getOptionOne(){
        return optionOne;
    }

    public String getOptionTwo(){
        return optionTwo;
    }   
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println(A.valueOf("THIS").getOptionOne()+ " - "+A.valueOf("THIS").getOptionTwo());
}
```

Comment: oh I see, that does resolve the error code I had, I'll have to work if that was problem with setting values too.

Comment: "Java's enums are themselves just like classes" - that's because enums _are_ classes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how nested types work in Java. In your example you have a class called 'A' with a nested enum also called 'A'. Even if Java allowed this name clash (it doesn't), it would be confusing. Which 'A' would we be talking about in a given situation?

Anyway, you don't need any nesting in this situation, you just need a regular enum defined like so:

```
public enum A
{
    FOO("1","2"), BAR("2","3");

    private final String optionOne;
    private final String optionTwo;

    A(String one, String two)
    {
        this.optionOne = one;
        this.optionTwo = two;
    }

    public String getOptionOne(){
        return optionOne;
    }

    public String getOptionTwo(){
        return optionTwo;
    }   
}
```

You can then say:

```
A.FOO.getOptionOne(); //1
A.FOO.getOptionTwo(); //2

A.BAR.getOptionOne(); //3
A.BAR.getOptionTwo(); //4
```

You may find it useful to [read up on enum definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: The OP's code did not have "an inner class also called A". Nested enums are never inner classes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9

Comment: "I don't even know whether this name clash will be allowed or not" - The error message this question is about demonstrates that it is not, if one pays attention.